# What is a noun for describing people who live in an arid environment?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Looking non-regional term that will work for people in anywhere from Arabia to California. Something similar to desertinian.

Comment: Will _desert dwellers_ work?

Comment: Sandpeople always ride single file to hide their numbers.  Member?

Comment: Deserters might give the wrong idea.:-)

Comment: _Deserters_ was my first impulse too! :)

Comment: Aridity implies only lack of moisture in the air, not temperature. The Atacama desert, for example is considered the driest non-polar desert. What I mean is that your definition would have to encompass cold weather dwellers as well such as Inuits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Desert dwellers*, as in the comment, or *desert people*, or *desert inhabitants*.

If you want to include those from arid lands that are not deserts, then you can say

*arid dwellers*